# THREE.js - Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am just learning to use Web GL and THREE.js

I followed a tutorial on YouTube and as a result ended up with the below code.  This code should display a cube and an axis.  However, when I try to display the page containing this code I get a Javascript error.  The error states:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.updateMorphTargets is not a function

I am not sure what I have done wrong but was hoping that someone here who was familiar with THREE.js could help me out.  Thanks so much for your time.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($){

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,.1, 500);
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    var axis = new THREE.AxisHelper(10);

    scene.add(axis);

    var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(5, 5, 5);
    var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xdddddd, wireframe:true});
    var cube = THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);

    cube.position.x = 0;
    cube.position.y = 0;
    cube.position.z = 0;

    scene.add(cube);

    camera.position.x = 40;
    camera.position.y = 40;
    camera.position.z = 40;

    camera.lookAt(scene.position);

    $('#webgl-container').append(renderer.domElement);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

});
```

Comment: Look at the stack trace of the error. What line is it originating from?

Comment: It's coming from line 16927 in three.js

when it tries to call this.updateMorphTargets();

Comment: Is that the origin of the stack trace? There's no functions calling that one?

Answer (score 21):

You made a simple typo, forgetting the `new` operator before `Three.MESH`, so it should be:

```
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);
```

The `new` operator is a big deal, without it the `THREE.Mesh` is no longer a constructor but an ordinary function. This causes the `this` inside the function to refer the `THREE` namespace object itself, as opposed to a newly created `Mesh` object. The `THREE` namespace object does not have an `updateMorphTarget()` method, hence the error.

Comment: You say: " The THREE object does not have an updateMorphTarget() method", but you mean the THREE namespace object.

Comment: Very true, the current wording could be confusing. I've edited the answer, thanks!

Comment: Brilliant observation!